# find if an element exists and then click on its corresponding button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If I have a page that has a list of elements, I need to find one specific element and click its actions button. Each element in the list will have its action button. I could write to locate the specific element but I am having trouble locating its corresponding actions button. So for example list page would be like below and I have to click action button of Test2

Test1 -- Action
Test2 -- Action
Test3 -- Action

Button text (Action) is common for every button.. Also I do not want to use xpath or its number since it might change if the list grows and every time i want to be able to click on the same element's Action button. Is there a way I can somehow use an "if else" and locate the name and then click its action button? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your TDs text, compare with your desired, get TR parent and find the action button. You can do it using pure XPath (that is not the best way) or using the language that you're working with Selenium.

As Example, in C#:

```
Browser.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"))
    .First(x => x.Text.Contains("my text to compare"))
    .FindElement(By.TagName("input"))
    .Click();
```

It will search in all "tr" tags the one that contains the text "my text to compare" and it selects only the first result that matches, and after will select the input tag inside it. Of course you can change the tag names or the selectors, you need adapt the code with your necessity

The same you can do using pure XPath selector:

```
$x("//td[contains(text(), 'my text to compare')]/..")
```

It will take the td that contains the desired text and get the parent tr. Afert it you can navigate to your desired tag and select your action button.